# How to get unique documents when searching indexed documents in lucene

Tags: lucene

I need to index documents and search them. I have multiple fields to query. When I search the indexed files, I am having repeated documents. This is how I made the query:

```
MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser( Version.LUCENE_40, new String[] {"title", "abs"}, analyzer);
```

Query query = parser.parse(querystr);

Here is my display:

```
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(hitsPerPage, true);
        searcher.search(query, collector);
        ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
        // 4. display results
        System.out.println("Found " + hits.length + " hits.");

        for(int i=0;i<hits.length;++i) {
            int docId = hits[i].doc;
            Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + d.get("pmid") + "\t" + d.get("title"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks OK, however it would be helpful if you printed `docId` value.

If this value is different, then you most likely have your document added multiple times to the index which you need to fix.

Remember, Lucene doesn't have built-in concept of identity. For Lucene all documents are different even if they have exactly same terms. The standard approach of fixing this problem is to have non-analyzed field containing some external ID (e.g. database id) and removing+re-adding updated document when changes happen.

Comment: My documents were indexed multiple times. Thanks.